# Magento - How can i run function when the checkout page is opened?

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and i am working on a custom extension.

My question is:
How can i run custom php function when the checkout page is opened?

I know i have to mess around with the events of the extension config file but i am not exactly sure how i can point the function in the observer which i want to run when the checkout page is opened.

Here is events part of my config:

```
    <events>

        <controller_action_postdispatch_opc_json_saveOrder>
            <observers>
                <hss_save_order_onepage>
                    <class>paypal/observer</class>
                    <method>setResponseAfterSaveOrder</method>
                </hss_save_order_onepage>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_opc_json_saveOrder>
        <sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
            <custom_ads>
                    <class>opc/observer</class>
                    <method>checkitemsincartv</method>
            </custom_ads>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>                
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <newsletter_order_place_after>
                    <class>opc/observer</class>
                    <method>newsletter</method>
                </newsletter_order_place_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>

         <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <opc_checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <class>opc/observer</class>
                    <method>applyComment</method>
                </opc_checkout_submit_all_after>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>

    </events>
```

Here is the function that i want to run:

```
public function checkitemsincartv($observer)
{
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setItemsInCart("Works");
    $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    Mage::log($data->debug(), null, "order.log", true);
}
```

How can i achieve that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the event - `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` or `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_index` All controllers inherit the preDispatch or postDispatch method which fires a generic event for predispatch/postdispatch, and a specific event based on the requested action path.

The controller you need is in the checkout module and is called onepage with a default action of index.

Checkout `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()` or `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::postDispatch()` to see the relevant code

Comment: I do not get it. I have updated my question and i have added the function which i want to run when the checkout page is opened. Can you please see it and give me full example ?

Comment: How come method name you have defined in config.xml & Observer are different?

Comment: I mean you need to call it like in config.xml check method section -
`<controller_action_postdispatch_opc_json_saveOrder>
            <observers>
                <hss_save_order_onepage>
                    <class>paypal/observer</class>
                    <method>checkitemsincartv</method>
                </hss_save_order_onepage>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_opc_json_saveOrder>`